# How to check if an id is an instance or a class?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Say I have a method:

```
- (void)method:(id)anObject
{
  // do something
}
```

As we all know Objective-C classes or objects too. So I've been wondering how do I determine if the id passed inside the method an INSTANCE of a class or a CLASS itself? Because it may be used it like:

```
[object method:[NSObject new]];
```

or:

```
[object method:[NSObject class]];
```

how can I find out that the passed argument is an instance? I can't check it just by sending `class` message because for a class it will return the same result as for an instance

EDITED

The approach provided by Alexander does not suits me because I don't know what class will be passed so I can't check for membership of a particular class. I just need to know if it is a class (no matter what class) or is an instance (of no matter what class)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classes return `self` from the `class` message, instances return their class. So just test if the result from `class` is identical to the receiver:

```
- (void)method:(id)anObject
{
    if (anObject == [anObject class]) {
        // it's a class
    } else {
        // it's an instance
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Though simple, there are two subtle problems with above code:

1. The receiver has to implement `class`. All `NSObject` (and `NSProxy`) derived classes do so but for custom root classes this might not be the case. Extremely rare.
2. If a class *does not* return `self` the code would break. This might be the case with classes of objects that are being observed (KVO). Not so rare.

Here's code that will always work and is immune to these issues:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

- (void)method:(id)anObject
{
    if (class_isMetaClass(object_getClass(obj))) {
        // it's a class
    } else {
        // it's an instance
    }
}
```